# Simple inequation equivalence with n as exponent

Tags: inequality

$5^{n+1 }-4 \cdot 5^n \geq 4 \cdot 3^n -3^{n+1} \iff 5^n \geq 3^n$  where $n$ is a positive integer
How is this possible? I can't find a connection. I put spaces to distinguish fractions.

Comment: What if $n = 1$?

Comment: I think there is a mistake on the given problem! The problem must have been stated like this: $4 \cdot 5^n+1 - 5^n \geq 4 \cdot 3^n -3^n+1$.

Comment: actually am stuck in formatting XD I knew I would do something silly :P the whole n+1 should be an exponent, not just the n.

Comment: Now its correct.

Comment: Hint $a^{n+1}=a\cdot a^n$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$5^{n+1}-4\cdot5^n\ge4\cdot3^n-3^{n+1} $$
So then you'll have: $$5\cdot5^n-4\cdot5^n\ge4\cdot3^n-3\cdot3^n$$ 
Now you can divide both sides of the inequality by $3^n$ and then you get:
$$5\cdot\left(\frac53\right)^n-4\cdot\left(\frac53\right)^n\ge1$$
$$\left(5\over3\right)^n\ge1$$
$$\left(5\over3\right)^n\ge\left(5\over3\right)^0$$
This means that $n\ge0$. So that's your solution! If something is unclear please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm right but you can try this:

$
5^{n+1}-4*5^{n} \geq 4*3^{n}-3^{n+1}\\
5^{n}*5-4*5^{n} \geq 4*3^{n}-3^{n}*3\\
5^{n}(5-4) \geq 3^{n}(4-3)\\
5^{n}(1) \geq 3^{n}(1)\ \mid:1\\
5^{n} \geq 3^{n}
$